# Does it require direct XML modification to prepare an SSIS package for different environments?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am maintaining some SSIS package I didn't build, and it creates an output file (`.txt`) and then emails that to a group. However, the package is actually fully configured for PROD. Some of the components I'll need to modify are: connection managers, pickup and drop off locations for the text file, mail servers, etc.

**Am I going to have to just modify the XML directly to get this deployed to other environments?**

Please note that I don't have access to do the deployments on these other environments - I simply have to hand it off to another team.

Comment: You can use SSIS configuration files for this

Comment: If `XML Configuration` is enabled for these packages ,then you can simply modify these `XML files` and execute it in other environments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd almost post this as a comment, but if you're unfamiliar with SSIS, it's worth noting that there are about 3 ways the package can be linked to the config files.

You can certainly modify the config files.  However, I'd regard setting up the config files for the environments as something the ops people should take ownership.  If you need to set up connections for your development environment you've a slightly more complex problem.

The package may get the location from an environment variable, in which case you can just set up the config file for your development environment and configure the environment variable to point to it.  You need to ensure that BIDS is running with the environment variable set, though.

If the configuration is supplied via a switch to DTExec you might be better off just setting the connections directly in the package.  In this case the package won't use the config file unless you specify a path with `DTExec /Config`

If the path is hard coded into the package (i.e. a specified path rather than an environment variable) then you can adjust that path.  However, the ops people will have to edit this as a part of the deployment process.  Alternatively you could write a little .Net app that did the update and use that as a part of the deployment.  The downside of this is it introduces scope for human error in deploying the packages.

If you need to maintain your config files manually I'd suggest you frig the indentation so it's a bit more readable.  By default SSIS puts no whitespace in the files, but it doesn't mind if you do.

Comment: +1 .You can use tools like http://ssisconfigeditor.codeplex.com/ which can change the path of config file in SSIS without actually opening it in BIDS when you copy the packages to other environments

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Based on this I'm going to have the ops people make the changes by hand this time -but I'd like to build the configuration files so I'm going to start the process of moving all of our packages to leverage configuration files. It's a long process and will take months to get through all the paperwork -but it will be worth it in the end!